USB-C Connector Misalignment: Contacts Elevated by 0.5mm from PCB Pads
We are integrating a USB-C connector, specifically part number USB4715-GF-A, which is rated IP-68. The CAD model used was obtained from componentsearchengine.com. Upon assembling the connector CAD onto our PCB CAD, we noticed that the connector's contacts are elevated by approximately 0.5mm above the corresponding PCB pads, despite the connector being fully seated. This seems unusual and could potentially impede soldering processes. Of course, the CAD model could be wrong, and we have yet to receive a sample of the part. But I want to ask has anyone else encountered this issue, or can provide insight into whether this is a typical scenario for this type of connector?  CAD image 1 

There is no misalignment issue and the CAD model is correct.
The data sheet says it is a mid-mount connector, and my guess is you did not make a PCB cut-out for the connector but are trying to mount it on top of the PCB like a standard SMD connector.
